# Open a local file through a PHP web service

Tags: php, web-services

I apologize if this is a pretty novice question but I'm learning PHP and have been having trouble writing a web service.

When I use `fopen($fullfilename, 'r')` it returns two errors:

> Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: remote host file access not
>   supported
>
> Warning: fopen(file://filepath) [function.fopen]: failed to open
>   stream: no suitable wrapper could be found

The filepath I'm using is the absolute path to the file on my local computer. I'm using a Mac if that makes any difference. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does `echo $fullfilename;` show?  Where is `$fullfilename` coming from?

Comment: The echo shows /Users/Dezapp/Downloads/test.jpg
I've hardcoded the fullfilename for now just to see if I can get it working

Answer (score 2):

```
echo( "<pre>");
$fullfilename = "C:\Users\Documents\hey.txt";

$gg = fopen($fullfilename, 'r') or die("file doesnt exist");


// for entire read of doc use file_get_contents($fullfilename)
$readtext = fread($gg, 3000); //read 3000 chars of doc 

fclose($gg);

echo $readtext;
echo "</pre >";
```

hope it helps, thanks

Comment: This returns the file does not exist line but I know that it does on my computer

Answer (score 0):

You could try the relative path from the php file where the

```
fopen($fullfilename, 'r')
```

line can be found

For example:

```
/*
/usr/You/Documents/project/myproject/myfolder/myscript.php
/usr/You/Documents/project/myproject/mydata/datafile.txt
*/    

$fullfilename = "../mydata/datafile.txt";
$contents = fopen($fullfilename, 'r');
```

Should work ok.

Comment: I don't want to use a relative path because any user should be able to use the web service to upload a file to my server. Thus, they would need to pass the absolute path to the web service

Comment: Ah - if you're trying to access files not on the server - you'll have to take a different approach. Take a look at '$_FILES' and submitting a form with '<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">'

Answer (score 0):

When accessing files on the local system, you don't need the `http://` or `file:///`.  You just need the path to the file, like if you were accessing from the machine itself.

You just need to do:

```
fopen('/path/to/file', 'r')
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it gives the error: "failed to open stream: No such file or directory" but I know the file exists because I'm copying the filepath from my computer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$filename = realpath($fullfilename);
var_dump($filename);
```

What does it return? If it returns bool(false), the path/file doesn't exist here.